# Make Nginx serve /static/index.html at / (root)

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn

I have managed to set up Django with Gunicorn and Nginx as to the point that it all works properly - except for one desired feature.

I would like to be able to serve /static/index.html when only accessing root (`/`) *without* changing the displayed URL in the browser.
I am not sure what to use here (rewrite or alias or something else?)
Here is my current nginx.conf

```
upstream test_server {
   server unix:/path/to/project/project.sock fail_timeout=10s;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name <IP>;

   location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

   location = / {
      alias /path/to/project/static/;  # Does not work! See comment below
   }

   location /static/ {
      alias /path/to/project/static/;  # works!
   }

   location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/project/project.sock;  # communicates with Gunicorn/Django
   }
}
```

Comment from above: Seems to forward path `index.html` as a request to Django, resulting in Django complaining "Not Found: /index.html" even though Django should not even know about this. Imo Nginx should simply return /static/index.html here without involving Django.

How can I correct this (still displaying `<IP>/` in the browser and not `<IP>/static/index.html`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was a bit different than the one suggested by AlexeyTen:

```
server {
   # listen, server_name, etc...

   location = / {
       root /path/to/project;
       rewrite ^/$ /static/index.html last;
   }

   location /static/ {
       alias /path/to/project/static/;
   }

   location / {
      # proxy ...
   }
}
```

`root` outside the location blocks did not work, neither did directly including it in the rewrite URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
   # listen, server_name, etc...

   root /path/to/project;

   location = / {
       rewrite ^ /static/index.html;
   }

   location /static/ {
   }

   location / {
      # proxy ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It forwards it all to Django

Comment: Show your real config

Comment: There is nothing else except for the real path names.
With your solution I get "Not Found: /path/to/project/static/index.html" in Django

Comment: Are you sure your request comes to this server?

Comment: **Show** real config. _There is nothing_ really often means you've just missed something…

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: And where is my `location = /` in your config?

Comment: I didn't put it in the question since this would somehow invalidate it. Simply imagine I have your location = / (which I do here on my server)

Comment: When using your solution (with root and rewrite) I get in the Nginx error log:
`open() "/static/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), ..., request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"`

Comment: If found the solution. See my own answer.

Comment: I can't significant difference